# Visual studio tablet simulator problems

Tags: visual-studio, microsoft-metro

I'm developing an app wiht VS2012, but when try to test it on the simulator, it never allow me to actívate tactile interactive mode.

Gestures never work on it. There is a special setting ?

TKS:

Answer (score 0):

From your simulator:

[image]

The icons on the right side of the tablet allows you to switch between mouse mode or touch gesture modes.

The arrow icon (third from the top) is the mouse point gesture.

The hand icon is touch gesture

The dual-arrow icon is pinch/zoom

The circular arrow icon is rotation.

Comment: In order to pinch/zoom, use the mouse wheel.

Comment: Tks for your answer.. but this is my problem, even if actívate touch mode , ítems never throw click, tap event.